# Custom 3 columns template [Bootstrap]

Tags: responsive, bootstrap-4

In my site I have a bootstrap grid template with 2 columns, like this:
[image]

I would like to add a box/column under under col-sm-4, respecting responsive bootstrap, like in this image:
[image]

Is it possible? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the grid system of Bootstrap column just be used for division the row, but you could create two rows in one column like following ways

```css
.block {
  background: gray;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" style="width:100%">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="block">
            A
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="block" style="background: red">
            B
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="block">
        C
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe this can achieve your need, but normally it is similar with add two block elements in left column

Comment: thank you so much for the easy but complete answer! This solves my problem! :) Have a nice day.